# Displaying call summary and balance details

Tags: iphone, voip

I am working on a iPhone application which has the facility to call any number using VoIP. For this i am using the SIP protocall. Now i want to show the user the call summary and the balance details. How can i do this? can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

To display a list of stuff you'd use a `UITableView`. You would need to define a cell that included all the details you want to show. There is lots of documentation on UI stuff like this on Apple's developer site.